# The type 'MaxLengthAttribute' exists in both 'EntityFramework, and 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I am doing some spring cleaning on a legacy Web Api 2 project (target 4.5).  As part of the the nuget updates, I moved Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage from version 5.0.0 to 5.2.3.  Once I do that, I am getting the following message:

> Error CS0433  The type 'MaxLengthAttribute' exists in both
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

It looks like this was a problem a while back when they moved that class from EF to DataAnnotations and the solution was to upgrade EF.  Since I have the most recent stable version of EF (5.2.3), I am not sure what else to do.  I tried removing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the using statements, but then it doesn't pick up the EF MaxLengthAttribute.  Cleaning and rebuilding the solution also does not work.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: "I have the most recent stable version of EF (5.2.3)"? Is there [such](https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework/5.0.0) a version?

Comment: This just sounds like a namespace conflict that arose, just use a well typed namespace for the problem areas.  EG: Say I had something like '(class)' and '(class2)' that both had a subclass 'child'.  If I was to reference something as 'child' in yet another class.  Visual Studio would scream it did not know what I meant.  But I could easily extend the namespace 'class.child' or 'class2.child'.  Generally VS 2015 and on should point this out automatically and help you fix it, for older VS's you need to do it yourself at the problem area.

Comment: @Sergey - you are right.  I have 6.1.3 of EF installed.  5.2.3 is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage version

Comment: @djangojazz I tried fully qualifying the code like thisL             { typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute), a =>
but VS2015 is still complaining

Comment: @JamieDixon are you sure you got all the places?  Was it just a single section this happened in?  I would see if you quote out just that line or else mock it somehow using something else and it disappears.  There are also weird cases of Visual Studio having cache errors but I have never seem them on namespace conflicts.

Comment: I resolved the issue removing both references and installing the lasted nuget packege for both. System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.4.0 and EntityFramework.6.1.3

Comment: For me, I was upgrading a .NET Framework app to .NET 6 version. I was getting the same error. after spending a lot of time figuring out why?. All I had to do was clean all my nuget cache and this version of EF was removed and everyone was happy :)